# A simple mv command in a BASH script

Tags: bash, file, mv

The aim of my script:

1. look at all the files in a directory ($Home/Music/TEST) and its sub-directories (they are music files)
2. find out what music **genre** each file belongs to
3. if the genre is **Heavy**, then move the file to another directory ($Home/Music/Output)

This is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd Music/TEST
for files in *
do
  if [ -f "$files" ];then
    # use mminfo to get the track info
    genre=`mminfo "$files"|grep genre|awk -F: '{print $2}'|sed 's/^ *//g'|sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9\ \-\_]//g'`
    if [ $genre = Heavy ] ;then
      mv "$files" "~/Music/Output/$files"
    fi
  fi
done
```

Please tell me how to write the mv command. Everything I have tried has failed. I get errors like this:

> mv: cannot move ‘3rd Eye Landslide.mp3’ to ‘/Music/Output/3rd Eye Landslide.mp3’: No such file or directory

Please don't think I wrote that mminfo line - that's just copied from good old Google search. It's way beyond me.

Comment: Does the `/Music/Output/` directory exist?

Comment: Google failed you this time; that `mminfo` piece is atricious. It shouldn't be hard to fix to use just a single Awk script.

Answer (score 4):

Your second argument to `mv` appears to be `"~/Music/Output/$files"`

If the `~` is meant to signify your home directory, you should use `$HOME` instead, like:

```
mv "$files" "$HOME/Music/Output/$files"
```

`~` does not expand to `$HOME` when quoted.

Comment: +0 The answer is fine, but it's a little odd that `~` doesn't appear in the error message, since `mv` should have received it as part of the second argument. I think this combined with ensuring that `~/Music/Output` exists is the full correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

By the look of it the problem occurs when you move the file to its destination.Please check that /Music/Output/ exits from your current directory.Alternatively use the absolute path to make it safe. Also it's a good idea not use space in the file-name.Hope this will helps.:)

Answer (score -1):

Put this command before mv command should fix your problem.

```
mkdir -p ~/Music/Output
```